# Type of malware on adult sites

Tags: malware

What kind of malware is there on random adults site?

When I open a video in such a sites there is weird effect of opening another window of browser which is immiedetely closed or opening another tab after click on video player.

I am wondering what malware is that and for what purpose is this. Just to read about it more.

I guess to be safe the only way is to not enter such a sites, right ?

Comment: The behavior you describe is not malicious. And it could be caused by a number of things.

Comment: Can you hint me some phrases (reason that can causes described situations) so I can google it out ?

Comment: Forest's answer is the best answer we can give.

Comment: I wouldn't rule out malicious-but-not-malware. Maybe browser fingerprinting, something ad related, CSRF, or referral traffic fraud. CSRF risks would be (and some privacy violations *might* be) reduced by not using the same browser profile you use for other websites.

Comment: Most of these sites probably have rogue javascript or phishing.

Answer (score 6):

What you are seeing is not malware, but an ad. Adult sites will very often open one or more new tabs or even windows to partner sites when you click on the page. This is not malicious behavior, although it can be very annoying. Basic ad blocking software should take care of that nicely.

Most of the time when there *is* malware on adult sites, it is distributed through downloaded executables or through outdated Flash or Java applets. Unless you have Flash installed or are gullible enough to download and run programs from pornographic websites, you should be relatively safe. To increase safety even more, make sure your browser is always up to date to avoid vulnerabilities.

Comment: Thank you for comment. But how is ad if the there is opened a new window and immediately closed ? And this is in the moment when I click first time on the video player to start a video. And this is situation is when AdBlockPlus is turned on.

Comment: @GuessMe I don't know, sorry. I have noticed the behavior too, and I am confident that it is not malicious. It could be something that pops up and is then closed by an ad blocker, or it might pop up, detect incompatibilities in the browser (e.g. no ActiveX support), and close. Hopefully someone else can provide the answer to that aspect of the question.